# Swift: Returning data from child ViewController via NSNotificationCenter

Tags: swift, notifications, viewcontroller

I have a table view controller with a Sort button that I'm using to allow the user to change the sort order of a tableview. I segue to the Sort view controller when the button is pressed, and pass in the current sort order, which a UIPickerView picks up and sets as the selected item.

If the user changes the selected item in the picker, I want to send that back to the parent view controller so it can re-sort the table.

So far I've seen 2 methods: setting up a delegate or using the NSNotificationCenter. I'd decided to try the latter.

In my SortViewController, I capture any changes pickerView:didSelectRow:InComponent and then post the new value as a named notification.

In the parent view controller, I added an addObserver call in the init for the view controller so that it's listening for that notification, but the notifications never get sent, apparently.

here's the code:

TableViewController:

```
var sortOrder: String = "Name"

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "setSortOrder:",
    name: "sortOrderChangedNotification",
    object: sortOrder )
```

Receiver function:

```
func setSortOrder( notification: NSNotification ) {
    // set the sort order
    println("Received sortOrderChangedNotification")
}
```

SortViewController:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    println("Picker view selection changed!")
    var selRow = sortPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sortOrderChangedNotification", object: sortMethods[selRow] )
}
```

I never get the println output from setSortOrder, which as far as I know can mean that a) the notification doesn't get pushed (even though the println in didSelectRow does print) b) it isn't being received by my observer or c) my observer is set up wrong.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I also tried using this version as well: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sortOrderChangedNotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["row": sortMethods[selRow]] )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `-addObserver:` declaration has to be like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setSortOrder:", name: "sortOrderChangedNotification", object: nil)    
}
```

Your `-postNotificationName` declaration has to be like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sortOrderChangedNotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["row": sortMethods[selRow]]) //userInfo parameter has to be of type [NSObject : AnyObject]?
```

Then, you can complete your `-setSortOrder:` method with `notification.userInfo`:

```
func setSortOrder(notification: NSNotification) {
    //deal with notification.userInfo
    println(notification.userInfo)

    println("Received sortOrderChangedNotification")
}
```

To stop observing:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, POB. That compiles fine, but I'm getting a crash whenever the notification gets posted (the pickerView is changed): [NSConcreteNotification count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa77acd64f0
2014-09-12 17:54:44.520 DeckMaster[7214:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa77acd64f0'. I also tried setting the object in the postNotificationName:object:userInfo to nil, since it's an optional. Same crash.

Comment: Ah, okay I found where it was crashing. I was passing a string to the sort view controller and that was misbehaving. Thanks, POB. Your solution worked fine.

Comment: getting crash 

[NSConcreteNotification count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170657d00
2017-02-22 11:55:48.694015 Reshotel[1141:571568] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170657d00'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: i have implemented  this code

viewController a:
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.getNotification(_:)), name: "notification", object: nil)
}

func getNotification(notification:NSNotification) {
        print(notification.userInfo)
    }

viewController b:
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notification", object: callInfoDetails)